# Android : Remove all shortcuts associated with the app from code

Tags: android, installation, uninstallation, shortcut, homescreen

I want to remove all the shortcuts on home screen of my app on a single event like button click.
Is there any way to do this ? or at least get the display-names of all the shortcuts placed on home screen from my app ?
( I cant have it in any shared-prefs / db while creation of shortcuts because user can even do a 'clear-data' )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
appShortcutIntent = new Intent();
appShortcutIntent.setClassName("com.pkg.pkgname", "MainActivity");
appShortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

appIcon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);

Intent intentDeleteShortcut = new Intent();
intentDeleteShortcut.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.INTENT", appShortcutIntent);
intentDeleteShortcut.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME", getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
intentDeleteShortcut.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.ICON_RESOURCE", appIcon);
intentDeleteShortcut.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(intentDeleteShortcut);
```

And add this permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Hope this helps.

(P.S: This will require the device to be rooted as far as I know.)